# How to fix images overlapping bootstrap

Tags: javascript, css, node.js, twitter-bootstrap, web-applications

I have written a node.js code to display 3 images and I am using bootstrap to style these images next to each other but the are overlapping when I use col-mid-"any number".

```
<% include partials/header %>
<div class="container">
<header class="jumbotron">
    <div class="container">
        <h1>Welcome to our locations</h1>
         <p>View our Camp grounds</p>
         <p>
         <a class="btn btn-primary btn-large" href="/">Home</a>
         <a class="btn btn-primary brn-large" href="/campgrounds/new">Add a new CampGround</a>
         </p>     
    </div>
</header>


<div class="row text-center" style="display:flex; flex-wrap:wrap;">
    <% campgrounds.forEach(function(campground){  %>
        <div class="col-md-3">
            <div class="img-thumbnail img-fluid">
                <img src="<%= campground.image %>">
                <div class="caption">
                    <h4><%= campground.name %></h4>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
       <% }) %>
</div>
```

Comment: Post the CSS please.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try setting the img-fluid css class on the img element itself rather than it's parent element.

```
<img class="img-fluid" src="<%= campground.image %>">
```

You were restricting the width of the image's parent element rather than the width of the image itself.

```
<div class="row text-center" style="display:flex; flex-wrap:wrap;">
    <% campgrounds.forEach(function(campground){  %>
    <div class="col-md-3">
        <div class="img-thumbnail">
            <img class="img-fluid" src="<%= campground.image %>">
            <div class="caption">
                <h4><%= campground.name %></h4>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
   <% }) %>
</div>
```

Here's a CodePen as an example: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/QoPNdb

Alternatively, you could set a broad css style like this if you just want to restrict all images inside bootstrap grids to fit within their containers.

```
.container > .row img,
.container-fluid > .row img  { max-width: 100%; }
```